# UserService NullPointerException Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I have a maven project with Spring/Hibernate and I keep getting NullPointerException at `this.userService.save(user);`. UserService is @Autowired, so I'm not sure why this throws NPE. 
code sample with UserService:

```
@Component
public class BotService extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private MessagesService messagesService;

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        Message message = update.getMessage();
        String text = message.getText();
        User user = new User();
        user.setTelegramId(message.getFrom().getId());
        user.setFirstName(message.getFrom().getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(message.getFrom().getLastName());
        Messages messages = new Messages();
        messages.setUser(user);
        messages.setId(user.getId());
        messages.setText(text);
        this.userService.save(user); // <-- NPE 
        }
    }
```

UserRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.model.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{
    User findById(int id);
}
```

UserService.java

```
import com.example.model.User;

public interface UserService {
    public User findById(int id);
    public void save(User user);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.example.repository.UserRepository;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(int id) {
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

UPD. Added detailed description

BotExampleApplication.java:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.starter.EnableTelegramBots;

import com.example.service.BotService;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTelegramBots
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BotExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();

        TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

        try {
            botsApi.registerBot(new BotService());
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SpringApplication.run(BotExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.service.BotService.onUpdateReceived(BotService.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380) ~[na:na]
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27) ~[telegrambots-meta-3.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:309) ~[telegrambots-3.6.1.jar:na]
```

[image: Package structure]

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you create `BotService`?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Please share the package structure, where have you defined your SpringBootApplication Annotation, the Implementation of ApplicationContext (your main method), and log to scrutinize further

Comment: Please check where you have defined component scanning. It might be scanning the wrong package.

Comment: Btw, it shouldn't be extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> instead Long?

Comment: The fact that it is annotated with Springs annotations doesn't mean spring will inject things. Judging by the fact that you are extending `TelegramLongPollingBot` the actual instance being used isn't a Spring managed instance (but rather some other framework) and hence those annotations are pretty much doing nothing.

Comment: I think I didn't defined component scanning, so how to define it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never create new instances of spring components. In your main class `BotService` is created by using `new`. This is not the same as the `BotService` instance that spring creates. `@Autowired` works only in spring components and because you are using a different instance, the dependency is never injected into it.

To make it work, get the `BotService` instance from spring context and then use that to register.

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(...);
BotService service = context.getBean(BotService.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add setter and getter 
`@Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
/* setter and getter forr user userRepository*/`

and so on in another file

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private MessagesService messagesService;
/*setters and getters here too */
```